# How to handle change of checkbox using jQuery using CLASS not ID?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a list of checkboxes and each checkbox has the same `class`.
How do I use jquery in order to detect the `click` or `change` event of a checkbox?
I need this, in order to load data and to show a modal for the clicked checkbox.

```
<div class="widget widget-4" style="float:left;padding:10px;">
                <div class="widget-head">
                    <h4 class="heading">Alert to Delivery Methods</h4>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div class="widget-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            foreach($model->model_alert_2_delivery_methods as $key => $alert) {                       ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                        echo $form->checkBox($alert, 'name', array(
                                            'name' => 'AlertDeliveryMethods[' . ($alert->id) . ']',
                                            'class' => 'modal__package_create_popup_alert_delivery_methods',)
                                        );
                                        ?>
                                    </td>                            
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                        echo $alert->name;
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.modal_package_create_alert_delivery_methods').change(
                function() {
                    console.log('evrika');
                }
        );
    }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: there was a double _ ; did not see that one on my pc; 10x guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**:

```
 $(document).on('change','.modal_package_create_alert_delivery_methods',function(){
     console.log('evrika');
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use J-query's ON function.

```
$('.modal_package_create_alert_delivery_methods').on('change',
            function() {
                console.log('evrika');
            }
    );
```

if you are using jquery version less than 1.7, use live() instead of on()

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mm").on("change",function(){
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type='checkbox' class='mm' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' class='mm'  value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' class='mm'  value='1'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .on() for Jquery>=1.7

Add this line in head part of html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

then add this coding at end of page

```
  <script type="text/javascript" > 
$(document.body).on('change','.modal__package_create_popup_alert_delivery_methods',function(){
   //do something here 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.modal_package_create_alert_delivery_methods').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    console.log($(this).val());
    //show the corresponding data
  }
})
```